# Button in listview duplicates in every 7 listview item. How to fix it?

Tags: c#, listview, windows-phone

I have some listview and button in listview item.
I implement button clicking

```
private async void buttonDownload_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    Button clickedBtn = (Button)e.OriginalSource; //or (Button)sender
    clickedBtn.IsEnabled = false;
}
```

That's works, but when I click on the one button every 7th button also disabled.
How to fix it?

Comment: Can you please add the `XAML` part? It is a bit unclear

Comment: http://pastebin.com/6MFDfX9S
Now answer for this question needs only for academic interest. Can you help with this problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29308554/how-to-set-property-isenabled-in-each-subitem-button-of-listview-in-windows-phon ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing this.
Create a property in your ViewModel and bind that property to the IsEnabled property of Button of your ListViewItem Template.

```
private bool isEnabled;
public bool IsEnabled
{
    get{ return isEnabled;}
    set{ isEnabled=value;
         NotifyPropertyChanged("IsEnabled");}
}
```